# Word2Vec: Is it possible to train with respect to weight in NLP?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I used `Gensim`'s `Word2Vec` for training most similar words.

My dataset is all posts from my college community site.

Each dataset consists of like this:

```
(title) + (contents) + (all comments)  // String
```

For example,

```
data[0] => "This is title. Contents is funny. What so funny?. Not funny for me"
```

So, I have around 400,000 datas like above and make them as a vector and try to train these data via `Word2Vec`.

I wonder that whether it is possible to make `Word2Vec` consider WEIGHT, which means, if I give an weight to certain data vector, `Word2Vec` train this data in a way that each word in this data vector has more strong relationship(similarity).

For example, If I gave a weight 5 to dataset, `I like Pizza, Chicken`, the word `Pizza` and `Chicken` (or `like` and `Pizza` etc) has strong relations than other data vector's words.

Would that be possible?

Sorry for poor explanation but I'm not native english speaker. If need more detailed info, please post comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such configurable weighting in the definition of the word2vec algorithm, or the gensim implementation.

You could try repeating those text examples that you want to have more influence. (Ideally, such repetitions wouldn't be back-to-back, but shuffled among the entire dataset.)

As a result, those examples will affect the underlying model's training more often, for a greater proportion of the total training time – shifting the relative positioning of the involved words, compared to less-repeated examples. That *might* have the end result you're seeking.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm thinking about, too!. This is pseudo code for what  I'm trying to do :  `if weighted: data[0] = ("This is title. Contents is funny. What so funny?. Not funny for me") * 3`. I think that it also worked.. but you said this is `back-to-back`, right? Why do you say it is not gonna work?

Comment: That'd have some effect, and likely in the direction you desire. But (1) you've created new training contexts, not in original data, around the seams ("…for me This is…"); (2) all the multiplied contexts happen right-after each other in iterated training. Part of the 'magic' of SGD comes from all examples, interleaved, tugging against each other in different directions. Clumping similar examples together is usually worse than having them randomly/evenly spread out. (It can even help a little, but is not strictly necessary, to reshuffle a corpus between training passes.)